# C program getenv() returns null

Tags: c, environment-variables

After I call `export EXAMPLE="exampleValue"` in terminal. I call command `printenv` I can clearly see my new environment variable.

I compile C program and run it and in code I call `getenv("EXAMPLE")`.
But it returns null every time, unless I call 
`getenv("PATH")` or `getenv("HOME")` or similar environment variables.

```
char* env_variable_name;
env_variable_name = getenv("EXAMPLE");
```

Any explanation why I can't get value of EXAMPLE?

Comment: Are you sure it's exported? Try `EXAMPLE=test my_command`

Comment: Are you running it under the same shell as `printenv`?

Comment: "*unless I call  getenv("PATH")*" are you saying `getenv` returns non-null for `"PATH"` or that after you call `getenv("PATH")` the call to `getenv("EXAMPLE")` works?

Comment: getenv("PATH") returns non-null for "PATH". C program is run in the same terminal.

Comment: what about @jspcal's suggestion of running`$ EXAMPLE=test ./a.out` ?

Comment: Thanks @Ryan it worked that way with EXAMPLE=test ./a.out.

Comment: @jspcal Does it mean it is not exported properly?

Comment: No, it means your shell secures environment and calls `execve()` with predefined set of variables. So, basically what you need is to inherit or access to the parent environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a program inherit environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034993/how-does-a-program-inherit-environment-variables) Good to read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/if-processes-inherit-the-parents-environment-why-do-we-need-export One more thing is to run the program under non-root user or otherwise.

Comment: @0andriy Can you explain a little more about this "secure environment" feature?  It sounds like it quietly ignores an `export`, which sounds counterintuitive...

Comment: @SteveSummit Perhaps I wasn't clear. Here is more detailed info: https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-selinux-list/2009-March/msg00033.html

Comment: @0andriy: the environment is secured by the kernel, not the shell. And if `EXAMPLE=test ./a.out` works, then so will `export EXAMPLE=test; ./a.out`, since there is no difference in the environment seen by the `exec` call.

Comment: The comments about selinux wackiness are almost surely unrelated to OP's problem.